# Download youtube playlist

Tags: node.js, audio, youtube, discord

I'm working on a Discord bot and I'm trying to figure out a way to make it play either an entire playlist from YouTube or be able to individually add links. Assets for this are Node.js, ESLint, ytdl-core, @discord/opus, and ffmpeg (from [this site](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples.html#play-music-from-youtube)).

The relevant code is as follows:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (message.content === '!play') {
        if (message.channel.type !== 'text') return;

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return message.reply('please join a voice channel first!');
        }

        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1snEYPg8TXs');
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            dispatcher.on('finish', () => voiceChannel.leave());
        });
```

There is no issues with the posted code, but as you can see it only allows for one YouTube video. I know nothing about ytdl or any related functions, so I tried to just make a var playlist = [etc.], which didn't work at all because apparently it's set up so that it's expecting a link. Playlist links only play the first song before finishing the action.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`ytdl-core` does not support downloading playlists. You might want to try another library (e.g. [ytpl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytpl)) to fetch the videos contained in a playlist and then pass it to `ytdl-core` one by one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it after I finish some food. Looks like it should be simple enough.

Comment: I tried this but it throws a few errors that are too long to paste here. First one is
title: exports.removeHtml(importantTxt.match(PLAYLIST_NAME_REGEXP)[1]),TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download playlist from Youtube, you must use [ytpl](https://github.com/TimeForANinja/node-ytpl/tree/master)  module ([see in directory example](https://github.com/TimeForANinja/node-ytpl/tree/master/example)).

```
npm install ytpl
```

Some library and variable:

```
const ytpl = require('ytpl');
const util = require('util');
let saveString;
var meta;
const url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRBp0Fe2GpglkzuspoGv-mu7B2ce9_0Fn"
const url_ = url.toString();
const id = url_.replace(/^.*=/i,"");
const search = await ytpl(id, { limit: 15 });
```

Next, for the string, you need to do some operations.
So you need to use this suit of command before using the json.(this is an example who work on my example on august 15, 2023 on node v18.17.0):

```
saveString = util.inspect(search, { depth: Infinity });
meta = saveString;
meta = meta.replace(/: *(\[|\{)/g,':\n$1\n');
meta = meta.replace(/ *(\}|\])([,\n])/g,'\n$1\n$2');
meta = meta.replace(/(\[|\{|,)[\n\t ]*(\{|\[)/g, '$1\n$2\n');
meta = meta.replace(/(.*):(.*), *(.*):(.*)/g, "$1:$2,\n$3:$4");
meta = meta.replace(/\n */g, '\n');
meta = meta.replace(/\n[ \t]*\n/g, "\n");
meta = meta.replace(/\n([^\,\{\[\]\}:]*):/g, '\n"$1":');
meta = meta.replace(/^/g, "\n");
meta = meta.replace(/("[^:"]*":) */g, '$1\n');
meta = meta.replace(/\n'/g,'\n"');
meta = meta.replace(/'(,|\n|\]|\})/g, '"$1');
```

then you can parse json data:

```
var myjson = JSON.parse(meta);
```

And to finish: you do that:

```
console.log("Playlist:");
for(let x in myjson.items){
 console.log("fichier:%s [id = %s]", myjson.items[x].title, myjson.items[x].id);
}
```

I hope to reply to the answer.